# How do I get java to output to a log when run from a batch?

Tags: java, shell, batch-file

I have a java file called "Ares.jar" that runs every 5 minutes via windows scheduled tasks, the batch calls:

```
java -jar Ares.jar >> Ares.log
```

I'm not seeing any error output, is there some way to make the errors (system.err.println / exception.printStackTrace(); )go to a file?

Thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
java -jar Ares.jar > Ares.log 2>&1
```

The second part of this command will redirect stderr to stdout, ensuring that both appear in the same file.

If you want regular logs and error logs in separate files, just use:

```
java -jar Ares.jar > Ares.log 2>Ares.error.log
```

You can get the full details of everything that is possible in the documentation, available from Microsoft:  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx

Comment: windows batch supports this redirection too?

Comment: +1 I don't know it. good to know. I have 0 experience with windows batch/command, only 4 commands I knew about: `cd, copy, dir, del` thx.

Comment: Hrm, is there a way to make it go out to a file like Ares.error.log instead?

Comment: Thank you so much, super-helpful.

Comment: this doesnt seem to work when using exect