# Adding java output to echo string of bat file

Tags: java, batch-file, jar, echo, stdout

I need to assign Standard out of java application added to an echo string of a bat file. Lets say java application writes "hello world" via System.out.println.

For an example I have a bat file mybat.bat.

```
 @echo off

    echo output=java -jar E:\FYP\MyApp\out\artifacts\MyApp_jar\MyApp_jar\MyApp.jar %1
```

**which does not give the output=Hello world**

How can I achieve that. Your help is really appreciated.

Thank You !

Comment: To output to File see: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14731162/how-do-i-get-java-to-output-to-a-log-when-run-from-a-batch]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I understand you - you want to assign the output of the java to variable.
May be this will do this for you:

```
@echo off
set "java_output="
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
for /f "delims=" %%J in ('java -jar E:\FYP\MyApp\out\artifacts\MyApp_jar\MyApp_jar\MyApp.jar %1') do (
      set "java_output=!java_output! %%J" 
)
endlocal & set java_output=%java_output%
echo %java_output%
```

Comment: Why you use `setlocal enableDelayedExpansion` here (The question was about a simple `hello world`)? It makes the thing more complex and it strips exclamation marks from the output.

Comment: I'm not sure how many lines will be printed...Although this solution is far from perfect

Comment: Thanks a lot for the replies. I tried this. For simple hello world application it just prints out hello world. What I need is output= hello world to be printed where java application outputs only "hello world". And I checked with an application which has several lines which just closed the command prompt instantly.

Comment: So you need the output without quotes?? And have you tried to set `pause` at the end of the script? And does your program throws an exceptions? They wont be handled with this script as the exceptions are printed in error stream

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. I used pause to view the output. When I used some complex string such as..                                             System.out.println( "<ns:ExecuteResponse service=\"WPS\">\n" +
                "  <ns:Process ns:processVersion=\"1.0.0\">\n"
               );                                                      it just closed the command prompt.

Comment: have you passed nulls?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `for` command to get the output of a program and assign it to a variable.

```
  @echo off
    for /F "tokens=*" %%o in ('java -jar E:\FYP\MyApp\out\artifacts\MyApp_jar\MyApp_jar\MyApp.jar %1') do set output=%%o
    echo %output%
```