# Run a non-executable jar from a batch file in the same directory

Tags: batch-file, jar

I want to run a non-executable jar from a batch file in the same directory.
I was using this

```
java -cp "%~dp0file.jar" main
```

But it doesn't work, what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: did you try `echo "%~dp0file.jar"` and make sure the path looks right?

Comment: Still doesn't work, the batch file just closes instantly

Comment: Is this the only line of code in your batch-file? And i hope you added a `pause` after the echo command to check if the path looks right.

Comment: Oh didn't know about pause, turns out I had a null pointer when I moved the jar file. Thanks I fixed it now.

Comment: Please post an answer, so I can choose it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to [this link](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/java-basics/exceptions/java-lang-nullpointerexception-how-to-handle-null-pointer-exception/) on tips to avoid an invalid path.

Next time for debugging, make sure you dont have `echo off` and then add a `pause` command to before and after where you think the problem is, see where it crashes, and whether you can pinpoint the exact line.

[This link](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/battech_debugging.php) shows a few good methods to help, but in the case of your small script, and [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14731162/how-do-i-get-java-to-output-to-a-log-when-run-from-a-batch) shows a way to get the error log of java when run from a batch-file.